# Does $-x^2$ does mean $-(x^2)$ or $(-x)^2$?

Tags: notation

When I see something written as:  $-x^2$ does it mean $-(x^2)$ or $(-x)^2$ ?

..and *why*? I can't apparently apply a streight PEMDAS rule to it

Comment: "E" for exponents.

Comment: But there is nothing in PEMDAS to indicate when/where the negative symbol should be parsed

Comment: See my answer...

Answer (score 2):

If it helps, think of it as $0-x^2$.  The **E**xponent wins first, then the **S**ubtraction.  Hence it means $-(x^2)$.

Comment: You can also think of it as $-1\cdot x^2$

Comment: Oh that might be better than my way.  You should post this.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why one should think of it like this? Like a rule?

Comment: @Brad  you'll get used to it.  The "rule" is PEMDAS.  E preceeds S.

Comment: Ah. So that's why you said to think of it like a subtract operation. I guess that's like saying "negative numbers are not notated with 'minus signs'. To show a number as negative, you have to subtract it by something". (I don't really believe this, though...) It also would mean that the $-1*x^2$ would have to actually mean $(0-1)*x^2$. (I'm used to very exact syntax rules...)

Comment: @Brad in that case you might like kcborys' idea better.  There, you consider it as $(-1)x^2$, and the order becomes exponentiation then multiplication by $-1$.

Comment: Downvoter, help me out.

Answer (score 0):

It means $-(x^2)$. Think of $-x^2$ as $-1\cdot x^2$, and then it becomes easier to understand.

Answer (score -1):

The products have always prioprity upon the sums. So $-x^2 = - x \times x = - (x^2)$.